# How do I deploy the Jenkins .WAR file as an Azure Website?

Tags: java, azure

I have found a few tutorials for building a .WAR file that can be deployed as an Azure website from scratch, but I'm wondering how (if possible) to deploy the Jenkins .WAR file as an Azure website.

I'm using Jenkins Master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-custom-upload/ - this link talks about how to install/run hudson on azure websites. Since Jenkins is based on hudson, it should be possible to deploy Jenkins as well.

I will try to deploy Jenkins on azure websites and post a comment here about my findings.